# Java program working on Windows 7, but not windows 8?

Tags: java, windows, jakarta-mail

You people are making me self conscious.. I will try to make this one better.

Okay, so this program (Don't kill me.. I downloaded it)  is only working on Windows 7 and Ubuntu as far as I can tell.  When you open it on Windows 8 it says "Java exception Error."

I'm thinking this has something to do with `catch(messagingException ex)` at the end of the file.  I admit, I don't know a whole lot about java, but you have to start somewhere.. don't you?  I do know java is for all platforms!

I have also tried this program with multiple files and multiple Gmail accounts... I even tried it with my Comcast email address.
I'm using the "JavaMailAPI" (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html) for the actual mailing part.

When I open it on terminal in Windows 8 it gives me this:

```
Exception in thread "Main" java.lang.noclassdeffounderror: java/mail/mailexception
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.langf.Class.privateGetDdecLaredMethods(Unkown source)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(unknown source)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(Unknown source)
caused by: java.lang.classnotfoundexception: java.mail.messagingException
at java.net.URLCLassLoader$1.run(unknown source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivaleged(native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(Unkown source)
at jaa.lang.CLassLoader.loadClass(Unknown source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown source)
... 6 more
```

**Here is the code:**

```
package testing;

import java.util.Properties;
import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Testing{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication("Email","Password");
                }
            });

        try {
                        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
                        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("Email Address"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse("Email Address to send "));
            message.setSubject("Subject");
            message.setText("Message");
                         String filename = "attachment location";
         DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
         message.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
         message.setFileName(filename);
         multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
            Transport.send(message);
            System.out.println("Done");
                } catch (MessagingException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Testing.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
}
```

If you need anything else about the program please ASK!

Comment: Apparently the `java.mail` package (JAR file) is missing on the computer with Windows 8

Comment: Which version of Java are you running on these systems? Which libraries are packaged with the app?

Comment: I am running Java 7u13 on both machines, and the JavaMail should be packaged with it.. but it doesn't seem to be.  I'm assuming that would be my problem, how do I package a library with the program?

Comment: no, javamail is not part of the base jdk.

Comment: I typed that in a weird way.  I'm running 7u13 on both computers.  I thought the javamail would be packaged WITH the jar file, not the program, but I guess not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You have to download Java Mail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-eeplat-419426.html#javamail-1.4.6-oth-JPR)

If JavaMail is needed by this application you should build an installer to package and install the needed JARs as JavaMail.

Comment: Thank you, but is there anyway to add this into the program itself? So that I don't have  to tell everyone to download it?

Comment: So all you have to do to get javamail on your computer is run "Mail.jar"?

Comment: Building apps for distribution is the job of a build tool. Have a look at [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/) and specifically the [application plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/application_plugin.html), which will generate batch and shell scripts for your app and build a zip or tar file with those, your code, and all required libraries.